# Ehrenfest Theorem and correlation among observables at the quantum scale

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, hamilton-equations

I am studying quantum mechanics and I encountered the famous Ehrenfest Theorem, which states that given an observable $A$, its expectation value time evolution is governed by $\partial_t\langle A\rangle=\frac{1}{ih}\langle[A,H]\rangle$. This is famously analogous through canonical quantization of Poisson Brackets to the fact that in Hamiltonian mechanics one has $\frac{dF}{dt}=\{F,H\}$.

One has that the Hamilton equations have the following analogous form:$$\partial_t\langle x\rangle=\frac{1}{ih}\langle[x,H]\rangle=\frac{1}{m}\langle p_j\rangle$$ $$\partial_t\langle p\rangle=\frac{1}{ih}\langle[p,H]\rangle=-\langle\partial_x U\rangle$$
Whereas the first is completely analogous to the first Hamilton eq., to have the complete analogy one needs to have $$\langle\partial_x U(x)\rangle=\partial_{\langle x\rangle} U(\langle x\rangle) $$ but this happens for at most quadratic potentials. But this must mean that at the classical level $\langle x^2\rangle=\langle x\rangle\langle x\rangle$, whereas $\langle x^2\rangle\neq\langle x\rangle\langle x\rangle$ at the quantum level. In some sense then at quantum level we have a kind of correlation.

Is there anything to this correlation concept?

Comment: Sense? It underlies the uncertainty principle, doesn't it?

Comment: @CosmasZachos well, then explain.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Matrix_mechanics_interpretation).  How, exactly, is your textbook handling it, instead?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I mean, I know the content of uncertainty principle. Given two observables A, B showing a commutator $[A,B]$ we have that upon measurement, our knowledge of the system is affected by uncertainties $(\Delta A)^2(\Delta B)^2\geq\frac{1}{4}\langle[A,B]\rangle$. But it is not uimmediate to me how this should imply what I asked.

Comment: $\Delta x \neq 0$.

Comment: And why, precisely?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, at the quantum level
$$
(\Delta x) ~^2= \langle (x-\langle x\rangle)^2   \rangle =\langle x^2\rangle - \langle x\rangle^2 >0 .
$$

Taking, w.l.o.g., $\langle x\rangle =0$ to simplify out irrelevancies, the only state with zero width, $\langle x^2\rangle=0$ has the δ-function as a wavefunction,
so then it is $|x=0\rangle$, an un-normalizable state which is not in the Hilbert space, and is *unphysical* (albeit useful as a component of physical ones),
$$
\langle x|0\rangle = \delta (x).
$$

All physical wavefunctions have non-vanishing width, typically of $O(\sqrt{\hbar})$ — which is what makes trajectories untenable in quantum mechanics. It's at the heart of the uncertainty principle, as stated.  <sub>(There are easier ways to see this in phase-space quantization, to be sure.)</sub>